# Powershell script from the Azure DevOps pipeline cannot access internet

Tags: powershell, azure-vm

An Azure VM provisioned and proxy settings are configured. When we do the remote login into the VM machine and insert powershell command as follows:

```
Find-Module dockeraccesshelper
```

We get the reponse:

```
Version    Name                                Repository           Description
-------    ----                                ----------           -----------
0.0.3      dockeraccesshelper                  PSGallery            Allow a user account to access the docker engine...
```

So it is obvious that from Administrative Powershell command line in the VM machine , I can query for a module in the powershell repository. To confirm it further I issued the following command:

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path "Registry::HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"
```

And I could see the proxy server listed. I could also see the proxy server listed under Environment Variable listings.

But If I try to execute a powershell script file on the VM from the Azure Devops Pipeline I get the following error:

```
WARNING: MSG:UnableToDownload «https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=627338&clcid=0x409» «»
WARNING: Unable to download the list of available providers. Check your internet connection.
##[error]PackageManagement\Get-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and module names 'VSSetup'.
```

It is understood that VM admin has more access rights than the Azure DevOps Build Agent. But it should at least be able to access the internet.

Let me elaborate more about what the powershell script is  doing :

1. Install some powershell Modules from the ps gallery.

If I run the following as inline command, I get the following response from the pipeline:

```
Log on to the computer with an account that has Administrator rights, and then try again, or install
```

'C:\windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules' 
by adding "-Scope CurrentUser" to your command. 
    You can also try running the Windows PowerShell session with elevated rights (Run as Administrator).

So it is also abvious that the build agent has to have an elevated access rights as admin to install/update modules. Any hint on how to do it ?

Comment: Did you set up your private agent on the Azuel VM?

Comment: it is a service agent. How to check if it is public or private ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#interactive-or-service